# Websphere Profile Creation Stuck at importConfigArchive

Tags: websphere, profile, windows-server-2012

I have installed a Websphere Application Server on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Evaluation and try to create a new profile using ProfileManagement Tool.
But it is always stuck at "Running configuration command : importConfigArchive".
 [image]

When I see the log file, it ends with this message

```
<record>
 <date>2017-09-29T10:36:40</date>
  <millis>1506656200757</millis>
  <sequence>4829</sequence>
  <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</logger>
  <level>INFO</level>
  <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</class>
  <method>messageLogged</method>
  <thread>30</thread>
  <message>Checking for wsadmin listener initialization</message>
</record>
```

Is there any configuration that I missed?

Answer (score 1):

Do sudo unlink /bin/sh $ sudo ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
and then start pmt to create profile.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014838043

Answer (score 1):

Another idea, which helped me since I was having some kind of shell issue on Windows 10 was to read the profile creation logs, and manually construct and issue the **manageprofiles** command in a new shell.

In my case, the steps I used after failing to create profile **failedProfile** were:

1. Navigate to  ***<WAS_INSTALL_ROOT>*/logs/manageprofiles/myProfile_create.log**
2. Look for one of the first entries:

```xml
  <class>com.ibm.wsspi.profile.WSProfileCLI</class>
  <method>invokeWSProfile</method>
  <thread>1</thread>
  <message>Incoming command line is: { "-create" ,"-profileName" ,"failedProfile" .... .. }</message>
```

3. Build a new command in a text editor from this, like:

```bash
  .\manageprofiles.bat -create -profileName goodProfile ... <all the rest>...
```

4. Copy/paste this command to execute into a new shell.

It seems there is some kind of known issue mentioned in the other answer here where there's an assumption that 'sh' maps to 'bash'.  I'm not that familiar, but the point is to ensure your command line is valid.